# How to make keypad.h library print out hexadeciamal integers

Tags: c++, c, arduino, keypad

I am using the keypad.h library on the arduino mega ADK. I am trying to make the keyMap strictly out of hex integers so I can output them for my bluetooth rn42 module, however the built-in .getKey() and .getKeys() functions only take and return characters. How would I modify this library to output the hex integers i need?

```
char Keypad::getKey() {
    single_key = true;

    if (getKeys() && key[0].stateChanged && (key[0].kstate==PRESSED))
        return key[0].kchar;

    single_key = false;

    return NO_KEY;
}


bool Keypad::getKeys() {
    bool keyActivity = false;


    if ( (millis()-startTime)>debounceTime ) {
        scanKeys();
        keyActivity = updateList();
        startTime = millis();
    }

    return keyActivity;
}
```

keypad.h Library: https://playground.arduino.cc/code/keypad

additional note: I tried to keep the characters and print using the serial library's conversion to hex ( Serial.print('a', HEX) )  But there aren't enough characters to give me the specific hex numbers i need for my RN42 bluetooth module

Comment: What output do you need to sent into your bluetooth module? Something like `0X4E` for example?

Comment: Yes,  exactly: 0x2A, 0xC5, etc.

Comment: Ok, a simple solution using `Serial` woud be `Serial.print(String("0X") + String(78, HEX));`. But I could try change the lib to return in HEX already :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in my additional note, I used the hex conversion tool but keep in mind I was only able to use it to convert character values like 'a' to hex, not intergers like the example I showed. If i was able to get integers passed to the print function, then I would have no issue. Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: I think even the integers would be parsed into hex using `String(78, HEX)`. Bur if you want I can share a function which transforms int into hex.

Comment: Which one of these transformations do you need?: `'1'` -> `0x01` or `'1'` -> `"0x01"`

Comment: Edras that would be great!  Cacahuete i need '1' -> 0x01